# Amazon S3 Content Type won't be set when doing a POST request

Tags: php, http, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

`AccessDenied Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: content-type`

When I have this

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="awsaccesskeyid"

my-access-key-id
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bucket"

my-bucket
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/png
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

images/anime_girl.png
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

my-policy
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

my-signature
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
------WebKitFormBoundaryZIsnhgiAKpAVIsBT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="anime_girl.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

However, if I completely omit the `Content Type` in the code below, the file gets uploaded but doesn't have the right content type.

```
        "acl" => "public-read",
        "awsaccesskeyid" => $s3->getAwsAccessKeyId(),
        "bucket" => $s3->getBucket(),
        "Content-Type" => $inputs['type'],
        "key" => "images/" . $inputs['name'],
        "policy" => $s3->getPolicy(true),
        "signature" => $s3->getSignedPolicy(),
        "success_action_status" => "201"
```

I've also tried adding the content type into the `policy` and I get this error

`AccessDenied Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "Content-Type", "image/png"]`

I tried few other recommendations and get this error

`AccessDenied Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "Content-Type", "image/png"]`

This is my cors configuration

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

So how can I specify the content type in another way or fix this?

### EDIT

When I omit any type of content-type (I don't specify any on the backend) I get a request payload like Ben's

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="awsaccesskeyid"

xxxx
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bucket"

xxxxx
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

images/Elf-Anime-Warrior-Wallpaper.jpg
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

xxxx
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

0BbpI0AP0wL3S1cBfo9n9tOp+N8=
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Elf-Anime-Warrior-Wallpaper.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryUjxIo0gCBYg7AqJt--
```

The issue is that in the bucket, the file has the content type as `binary/octet-stream` and so the image isn't viewed in the browser but instead it's downloaded (which is not what i want). So I'm not sure why Amazon is not setting the content type appropriately when my request payload looks like the above.

Comment: could it be as simple as that field name should be `ContentType` rather than `Content-Type` when sending the upload/putobject request?

Comment: @SCuzzy you got me excited for a second. I tried that and got a similar error `Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: contenttype`

Comment: Do you have the character case right? ie `ContentType` and not `contenttype`

Comment: @Scuzzy yup, it just shows up like that in the error response. I did try `ContentType`

Comment: Ok false start sorry, I've used the S3 PHP SDK and my `ContentType` value appears to be stored within a `params` level array key as a sub-array, eg: `array('params' => array('ContentType' => 'image/png'))`

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 15):

According to [Amazon S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html), you can indeed pass the `Content-Type` as a form field, but [you need to allow that in your policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html).

So you'll need something like this:

**Policy:**

```json
{
  "expiration": "2007-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"acl": "public-read" },
    {"bucket": "johnsmith" },
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/eric/"],
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
    ...
  ]
}
```

The relevant line here is `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""]`. The documentation states that a condition of type "match any" should be a "starts-with" with an empty value. If you want to restrict the content type to something, you should use `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"]`, for example.

**Form:**

(example taken from S3 documentation, change values accordingly).

```html
<form action="http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="user/user1/${filename}">
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="binary/octet-stream">
  <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value='<Base64-encoded policy string>'>
  <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274">
  <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<signature-value>">
  <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request">
  <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256">
  <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date" value="20130806T000000Z">

  Tags for File: 
  <input type="input" name="x-amz-meta-tag" value=""><br>
  File: 
  <input type="file" name="file"><br>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3">
</form>
```

As you already did in your first payload, you did set a "Content-Type" field for the form. This, together with the updated policy, should work.

As a side note though, if you know beforehand the type of the file you are uploading, you should set both the policy and the form field to that type. But if you are uploading files of different types, you set the Content-Type condition to "match any" in the policy and you can write a simple javascript intercepting the `submit` event of the form to dynamically change the `Content-Type` field (here written with the help of jQuery):

```js
$("#s3-form").on("submit", function() {
  var contentTypeField = $("input[name='Content-Type']", this),
      fileField = $("input[type='file']", this),
      selectedFiles = fileField.get(0).files;

  if (files.length > 0) {
    // we're uploading a single file, so get the type for the first selected file
    contentTypeField.val(selectedFiles[0].type);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have the policy set up correctly, my files upload fine, the content-type is sent in the form data but the Content-Type is always blank when I check the file in the console in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample working request payload when I upload a file to S3:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9Vtjs2zgAF5jJgHC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

uploads/tmp/dbdfc12f-665e-4389-a739-f345e7acea48/svg_3927.zip
------WebKitFormBoundary9Vtjs2zgAF5jJgHC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="AWSAccessKeyId"

xxx
------WebKitFormBoundary9Vtjs2zgAF5jJgHC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"

public-read
------WebKitFormBoundary9Vtjs2zgAF5jJgHC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"

xxx
------WebKitFormBoundary9Vtjs2zgAF5jJgHC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="signature"

xxx=
------WebKitFormBoundary9Vtjs2zgAF5jJgHC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"

201
------WebKitFormBoundary9Vtjs2zgAF5jJgHC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="svg_3927.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
```

As you can see the Content-type is set only once, together with the file data, at the end.

**Update:**

Here are the CORS for my dev bucket:

```
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Notice `<AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>`, which might solve your problem.

Comment: Updated the question with a similar request payload as you. Even then, the content -type is not being set.

Comment: Actually I just checked a random image in my bucket and saw that the content-type was also set as `binary/octet-stream`. It works fine if used within an `<img>` tag or with `background-img`.

Comment: What do you mean used within an <img> tag? The upload button? I'm using an upload button that sends a request to the server to sign it and then sends the request to amazon with the signed credentials,

Comment: "the image isn't viewed in the browser but instead it's downloaded": it seems to me that that's the real problem you're trying to fix. In which way are you trying to render the image or making it accessible to users of your app?

Comment: ben, the only reason that is being a problem is because of the content type being set as binary/octet-stream instead of the right content-type. I just want it displayed like a normal image. That's it.

Comment: The binary/octet-stream content type is not a problem to display images as images if you put your image link inside a <img> tag or use background-image. Have you tried doing so?

Comment: I think he wants it to display in the browser when using the absolute url. Plus his original question was about the content type.

Comment: What he said. I want to know how to get the content type right.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't helpful. Please see my answer update.

Answer (score -1):

Try offsetting `ContentType` within a 'prams' level array..

```
"acl" => "public-read",
"awsaccesskeyid" => $s3->getAwsAccessKeyId(),
"bucket" => $s3->getBucket(),
"key" => "images/" . $inputs['name'],
"policy" => $s3->getPolicy(true),
"signature" => $s3->getSignedPolicy(),
"success_action_status" => "201",
// indent "ContentType" within a "params" array
"params" => array(
    "ContentType" => $inputs['type']
)
```

Comment: `AccessDenied Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: params`

That's the error I get.